# SVG background with transparent letters to see the other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I need to have a video running, and of top of it a black div with opacity less than 1 but with some text transparent to allow the user to see the video behind, and also a button with the same effect.

This is a picture of what I am looking for:

[image]

I manage to this in another release by using a png covering the video area, but now I need that button to have the same effect and I though about SVG, but I don't know if it is exactly true that I can use it or how.

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to look into SVG masks but other than the the question is too broad I feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do it using an SVG image overlaying the background.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480"/>

<svg id="overlay" width="640" height="480" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mymask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <text x="320" y="140" text-anchor="middle" font-size="40px" >Some transparent text</text>
      <text x="320" y="190" text-anchor="middle" font-size="40px" >has been placed here</text>
      <rect x="220" y="300" width="200" height="50" fill="black"/>
      <text x="320" y="335" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="30px">BUTTON</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <rect fill="black" fill-opacity="0.7" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mymask)"/>
</svg>
  
</div>
```